# NullPointerException in unit tests after migrating from groovy to kotlin gradle script

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I have no idea what's happening here, there shouldn't be a connection. Not one that manifests this specifically, anyways.

After moving the buildscript of a major spring-boot project from groovy to kotlin-DSL, some unit tests are throwing NullPointerException. It's all the unit tests that deal with methods that have manual transaction management using a TransactionTemplate. This has not happened before the move, and by now I have compared the old and the new buildscript a dozen times over and am pretty confident that I didn't forget anything.

Let's start out by comparing the two versions of the build scripts.

Old groovy:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.4.10'
        springBootVersion = '2.3.3.RELEASE'
        awsSdkVersion = '1.11.381'
        springfoxVersion = '2.9.2'
        kotlintestVersion = '3.1.7'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlinVersion"

        // liquibase stuff
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.44'
        classpath 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.19'
        classpath('org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.3') {
            exclude group: "org.liquibase", module: "liquibase-core"
        }
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.3" // should be in sync with the version included in spring boot
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'net.researchgate.release' version '2.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'org.liquibase.gradle'
apply plugin: 'idea'

group = 'webcam.yellow.service'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url = "http://clojars.org/repo/" }
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "${mavenUser}"
            password "${mavenPassword}"
        }
        url = "https://artifactory.yellow.webcam/artifactory/releases"
    }

    maven {
        credentials {
            username "${mavenUser}"
            password "${mavenPassword}"
        }
        url = "https://artifactory.yellow.webcam/artifactory/snapshots"
    }

}

idea {
    module {
        // if you hate browsing Javadoc
        downloadJavadoc = false
        // and love reading sources :)
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    // avisec libraries
    compile "webcam.yellow.api:webcam-api:3.2.0"
    compile "webcam.yellow.authentication:messaging-authentication:1.5"

    // Spring Boot
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-influx'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda'

    // Joda
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time'
    compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:6.0.1.GA'

    // Libraries
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.8'

    // Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}"

    // Mail
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-email', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.5.0-b01'

    // AWS
    compile "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:$awsSdkVersion"
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-sqs', version: '1.11.558'
    compile group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', name: 's3', version: '2.10.61'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-ec2', version: '1.11.740'

    // Support old pw hash lib
    compile group: 'buddy', name: 'buddy-hashers', version: '1.3.0'

    // Hazelcast
    compile group: 'com.hazelcast', name: 'hazelcast-spring'
    compile group: 'com.hazelcast', name: 'hazelcast-aws', version: '2.4'

    // Swagger
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: springfoxVersion
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: springfoxVersion

    // Database
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    runtime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    compile 'org.influxdb:influxdb-java:2.13'

    // HTML Generation
    compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', name: 'kotlinx-html-jvm', version: '0.6.10'
    //  ActiveMQ
    compile group: 'org.messaginghub', name: 'pooled-jms'

    // Development
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"

    // Testing
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testCompile 'com.h2database:h2'
    testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest:2.0.7'
    testCompile 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.6.0'


    // GSON
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile '/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'
            url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/yellow'
            username 'user'
            password 'secret'
            classpath 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}


springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

task ebextensions(type: Exec) {
    executable "sh"
    args "-c", "jar uf build/libs/webcam-service*.jar .ebextensions"
}

bootJar.finalizedBy ebextensions

afterReleaseBuild.dependsOn bootJar

test {
    minHeapSize = "1024m"
    maxHeapSize = "1024m"
    jvmArgs = ["-Xloggc:build/gclog-%p.log", "-XX:+PrintGCDetails"]
}
```

And the new kotlin one:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.6")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:1.4.10")
        // liquibase stuff
        classpath("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.44")
        classpath("org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.19")
        classpath("org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.3") {
            exclude("org.liquibase", "liquibase-core")
        }
        classpath("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.9") // should be in sync with the version included in spring boot
    }
}

val awsSdkVersion = "1.11.740"
val springfoxVersion = "2.9.2"


plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.3.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    id("net.researchgate.release") version "2.6.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.10"
    `maven-publish`
    id("com.jfrog.artifactory") version "4.14.1"
    id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.0.4"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.4.10"
}

group = "webcam.yellow.service"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

val mavenUser: String by project
val mavenPassword: String by project
val artifactoryRepository = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_REPO") ?: "snapshots"


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username = mavenUser
            password = mavenPassword
        }
        url = uri("https://artifactory.yellow.webcam/artifactory/releases")
    }

    maven {
        credentials {
            username = mavenUser
            password = mavenPassword
        }
        url = uri("https://artifactory.yellow.webcam/artifactory/snapshots")
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Spring Boot
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")


    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-influx")

    // Kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.6.8")

    // Yellow Dependencies
    implementation("webcam.yellow.api:webcam-api:3.2.0")
    implementation("webcam.yellow.authentication:messaging-authentication:1.5")

    // AWS
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:$awsSdkVersion")
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.10.61") // does not yet incorporate all functionality of 1.11.X
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:$awsSdkVersion")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:$awsSdkVersion")

    // Support old pw hash lib
    implementation("buddy:buddy-hashers:1.3.0")

    // Jackson
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda")

    // Hazelcast
    implementation("com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring")
    implementation("com.hazelcast:hazelcast-aws:2.4")

    // Other Libs
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.1")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.8")

    implementation("org.messaginghub:pooled-jms")
    implementation("org.influxdb:influxdb-java:2.13")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.6.10")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6")
    implementation("joda-time:joda-time")
    implementation("org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:6.0.1.GA")


    // Swagger
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:$springfoxVersion")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:$springfoxVersion")

    // Database
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    runtimeOnly("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    implementation("org.influxdb:influxdb-java:2.13")


    // Test
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.6.0")
    testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest:2.0.7")

}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

liquibase {
    activities.register("main") {
        arguments = mapOf(
            "changeLogFile" to "/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml",
            "url" to "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/yellow",
            "username" to "user",
            "password" to "secret",
            "classpath" to "src/main/resources"
        )
    }
}


tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }

    bootJar {
        from("./.ebextensions") { into(".ebextensions") }
        launchScript()
    }

    afterReleaseBuild {
        dependsOn(bootJar)
    }

    test {
        minHeapSize = "1024m"
        maxHeapSize = "1024m"
        jvmArgs = listOf("-Xloggc:build/gclog-%p.log", "-XX:+PrintGCDetails")
    }
}
```

Some things needed different handling, like moving some plugins from the classpath to the plugins section, the .ebsextensions are handled differently, and Jacoco isn't in there anymore because we  never really used those reports in jenkins. All in all, pretty normal. Everything works, except for this one thing in the unit tests.

Here's a class initialisation and one of the tested methods:

```
@Service
class ImageService(private val imageRepository: ImageRepository,
                   private val imageSetRepository: ImageSetRepository,
                   private val permissionService: PermissionService,
                   private val s3Service: S3Service,
                   private val entityManager: EntityManager,
                   private val panoFeedRepository: PanoFeedRepository,
                   private val panoImageRepository: PanoImageRepository,
                   private val jobFacade: JobFacade,
                   private val jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate,
                   transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager,
                   @Value("\${service.cleanup.enabled}")
                   private val cleanupEnabled: Boolean) {


    private val readTransaction = org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate(
            transactionManager,
            DefaultTransactionDefinition().apply {
                isReadOnly = true
                propagationBehavior = TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW
            })
    private val writeTransaction = org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate(
            transactionManager,
            DefaultTransactionDefinition().apply {
                isReadOnly = false
                propagationBehavior = TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW
            })


    /**
     * Deletes all passed images from the database while removing them from S3 asynchronously.
     * Does not check any permissions.
     * This opens its own write transaction, which could take a long time. If individual transactions take too long,
     * invoke this method multiple times with smaller chunks to avoid issues with table locking.
     * Since this is potentially long-running, commit preceding transactions beforehand.
     */
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    internal fun delete(images: List<ImageIdAndImageKeyAndImagePreviewKey>) {
        images.chunked(500).forEach { chunk ->
            log.debug("Deleting s3 files of {} images", chunk.size)
            jobFacade.executeAsync {
                val keysToDelete = chunk
                        .flatMap { listOf(it.getImageKey(), it.getImagePreviewKey()) }
                        .asSequence()
                        .filterNotNull()
                        .filter { !it.isBlank() }
                        .toList()


                s3Service.deleteImages(keysToDelete)
                log.trace("deleted {} s3 files of {} images", keysToDelete.size, chunk.size)
            }
            log.debug("Deleting {} images from database", chunk.size)
            writeTransaction.execute {
                imageRepository.deleteAllByIdIn(chunk.map { it.getId()!! })
            }   // <---- Exception happens in here
            log.trace("Deleted {} images from database", chunk.size)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a test setup and a test that tests tat method:

```
class ImageServiceTest {

    private val imageRepository: ImageRepository = mock()
    private val imageSetRepository: ImageSetRepository = mock()
    private val permissionService: PermissionService = mock()
    private val s3Service: S3Service = mock()
    private val hazelCastInstance: HazelcastInstance = mock()
    private val panoFeedRepository: PanoFeedRepository = mock()
    private val panoImageRepository: PanoImageRepository = mock()
    private val jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate = mock()
    private val transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager = mock()
    private val jobFacade: JobFacade

    private val sut: ImageService

    init {
        val imap: IMap<String, String> = mock()
        `when`(hazelCastInstance.getMap<String, String>(any())).thenReturn(imap)
        jobFacade = JobFacade(hazelCastInstance)
        sut = ImageService(
                imageRepository, imageSetRepository, permissionService, s3Service, mock(),
                panoFeedRepository, panoImageRepository, jobFacade, jdbcTemplate, transactionManager, false)
    }

    @Test
    fun `deleting multiple images invokes S3Service in chunks and deletes images from DB`() {
        val user = TestModelFactory.userWithOneCameraAndTablePermission()
        val table = user.tablePermissions.first().table!!
        val images = (1..800).map { TestModelFactory.image(table = table) }

        sut.delete(images.map { ImageIdentifiers(it.id, it.imageKey, it.imagePreviewKey) })
        Thread.sleep(2000) //leave enough time for S3 uploads to finish

        val idChunks = images.map { it.id }.chunked(500)
        verify(imageRepository, times(1)).deleteAllByIdIn(eq(idChunks[0]))
        verify(imageRepository, times(1)).deleteAllByIdIn(eq(idChunks[1]))
        verify(s3Service, times(2)).deleteImages(any())
    }
```

And finally, the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method webcam.yellow.service.service.ImageService$delete$$inlined$forEach$lambda$2.doInTransaction, parameter it
```

Now, there's several things I'm currently looking into about what might go wrong, involving the mocked TransactionManager and the non-mocked TransactionTemplates... But the *really frustrating* thing is that this simply didn't happen before migrating the build script, and nothing else changed.

Comment: What is the output of `gradle dependencies` in both cases?

Comment: Are you sure `TestModelFactory.image(table = table).id != null` in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the transactionTemplate (which is not mocked) invoked a method on the mock of the platformTransactionManager, which returned null (obviously), and that caused the NullPointerException.

It was fixed relatively easily by configuring the mock instance to return a value instead:

```
given(transactionManager.getTransaction(any())).willReturn(mock())
```

What I *don't* know is why this ever worked before. This problem should *always* have been there, but it wasn't... Only when I migrated the build file did it show its head, which doesn't really make much sense.